# Assertion error when making an MP4 video out of numpy arrays with OpenCV

Tags: numpy, opencv, mp4, fourcc

I have this python code that should make a video:

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

out = cv2.VideoWriter("/tmp/test.mp4",
                      cv2.VideoWriter_fourcc(*'MP4V'),
                      25,
                      (500, 500),
                      True)
data = np.zeros((500,500,3))
for i in xrange(500):
    out.write(data)

out.release()
```

I expect a black video but the code throws an assertion error:

```
$ python test.py
OpenCV(3.4.1) Error: Assertion failed (image->depth == 8) in writeFrame, file /io/opencv/modules/videoio/src/cap_ffmpeg.cpp, line 274
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 11, in <module>
    out.write(data)
cv2.error: OpenCV(3.4.1) /io/opencv/modules/videoio/src/cap_ffmpeg.cpp:274: error: (-215) image->depth == 8 in function writeFrame
```

I tried various fourcc values but none seem to work.

Comment: You didn't specify data type in `np.zeros` -- by default it's a 64bit float, but the VideoWriter only supports 8bit channel depth.

Comment: Exactly! Just use the line `data = np.zeros((500,500,3), dtype = np.uint8)` instead.

Answer (score 2):

According to @jeru-luke and @dan-masek's comments:

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

out = cv2.VideoWriter("/tmp/test.mp4",
                      cv2.VideoWriter_fourcc(*'mp4v'),
                      25,
                      (1000, 500),
                      True)

data = np.transpose(np.zeros((1000, 500,3), np.uint8), (1,0,2))
for i in xrange(500):
    out.write(data)

out.release()
```

Comment: Also have a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51914683/how-to-make-video-from-an-updating-numpy-array-in-python/51915019#51915019) where the data is normalized before writing it to video.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that you did not specify the data type of elements when calling [`np.zeros`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.zeros.html). As the documentation states, by default numpy will use `float64`.

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> np.zeros((500,500,3)).dtype
dtype('float64')
```

However, the `VideoWriter` implementation only supports 8 bit image depth (as the "(image->depth == 8)" part of the error message suggests).

The solution is simple -- specify the appropriate data type, in this case `uint8`.

```
data = np.zeros((500,500,3), dtype=np.uint8)
```